# SQL Server Convert

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have little problem with converting 
7,80E+18 ( store as varchar )  to 7800000000000000000 ( also store as varchar )

Any ideas how to do this in SQL Query. I can't modify the source file

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert it to a `decimal`:

```
select cast(7.80E+18 as decimal(20, 0));
```

You can then convert this to a string if you like:

```
select cast(cast(7.80E+18 as decimal(20, 0)) as varchar(255));
```

Here is a [Rextester](http://rextester.com/BIB5183).

EDIT:

You can first cast to a `float`:

```
   cast(cast(cast('7.80E+18' as  float) as decimal(20, 0)) as varchar(255)) ,
```

Comment: But when I'm store value 7.80E+18 as a varchar in table I get error during the converting. So this one is not working 
select cast(cast('7,80E+18' as decimal(28, 0)) as varchar(128))

Comment: @Piotr . . . Change the comma to a decimal.  SQL Server might be fidgety about that.